# R sweave generating only .eps

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I'm using R sweave (*.Rnw) and want to generate only plotname.eps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\SweaveOpts{eps=TRUE}

<<plotname, fig=TRUE, echo=F, prefix=F>>=
ggplot(data=data, aes(x = day, y = outside_act)) 
@

\end{document}
```

When I compile this code, three plots are generated: plotname.eps and plotname.pdf.
How can I suppress R sweave from generating plotname.pdf? (I only need plotname.eps and I don't want R sweave to run this chunk an additional times.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\SweaveOpts{eps=TRUE, pdf=FALSE}`.  For full details on the options available, run `vignette("Sweave")` in the R console.

However, if all you want is the EPS file and not the document, you can just generate it directly, using

```
setEPS()
postscript("filename.eps")
ggplot(data=data, aes(x = day, y = outside_act)) 
dev.off()
```

in an R script.